# R - tm package: Reduce the number of term matrix for the creation of a term-term adjacency visualization

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, adjacency-matrix

I am having problems to make a reproducible term-term adjacency visualization of my corpus, which has about 800K words.

I am following [a tutorial](https://rdatamining.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/an-example-of-social-network-analysis-with-r-using-package-igraph/) whose term matrix contains just 20 terms, and therefore, the result is optimal:

[image: Term-Term Adjacency Graph]

I figure, that my problem is that I am not able to reduce my term matrix to, lets say, the 50 most relevant terms of my corpus. I have found a comment from a site outside SO that could help, but I am not able to adapt it to my needs. In this comment, there is said, that I should have to play with my bounds when I create the Term matrix, so I ended with this code:

```
dtm2 <- DocumentTermMatrix(ds4.1g, control=list(wordLengths=c(1, Inf), +
bounds=list(global=c(floor(length(ds4.1g)*0.3), floor(length(ds4.1g)*0.6)))))


tdm92.1g2 <- removeSparseTerms(dtm2, 0.99)

tdm2.1g2 <- tdm92.1g2

# Creates a Boolean matrix (counts # docs w/terms, not raw # terms)
tdm3.1g <- inspect(tdm2.1g2)
tdm3.1g[tdm3.1g>=1] <- 1 

# Transform into a term-term adjacency matrix
termMatrix.1gram <- tdm3.1g %*% t(tdm3.1g)
```

So, if I am understanding this correctly, I can make the Term-Matrix get only those terms that appears at least in 30% of my documents, but not in more than 60 % of them.

However, no matter how I define this bounds, my term matrix `termMatrix.1gram` have always 115K elements, whose make impossible a visualization as I want. Is there a way to limit this elements to, let say, just 50 elements?

***How do I get my corpus?***

Just for clarification, I write down here the code I use to generate my corpus with the tm package:

```
#specify where is the directory of the files.
folderdir <- paste0(dirname(myFile),"/", project, "/")

#load the corpus.
corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(folderdir, encoding = "UTF-8"), readerControl=list(reader=readPlain,language="de"))
#cleanse the corpus.
ds0.1g <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
ds1.1g <- tm_map(ds0.1g, content_transformer(removeWords), stopwords("german"))
ds2.1g <- tm_map(ds1.1g, stripWhitespace)
ds3.1g <- tm_map(ds2.1g, removePunctuation)
ds4.1g <- tm_map(ds3.1g, stemDocument)
ds4.1g <- tm_map(ds4.1g, removeNumbers)
ds5.1g   <- tm_map(ds4.1g, content_transformer(removeWords), c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g","h","i","j","k","l",
                                                               "m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"))
#create matrixes.
tdm.1g <- TermDocumentMatrix(ds4.1g)
dtm.1g <- DocumentTermMatrix(ds4.1g)
#reduce the sparcity.
tdm89.1g <- removeSparseTerms(tdm.1g, 0.89)
tdm9.1g  <- removeSparseTerms(tdm.1g, 0.9)
tdm91.1g <- removeSparseTerms(tdm.1g, 0.91)
tdm92.1g <- removeSparseTerms(tdm.1g, 0.92)

tdm2.1g <- tdm92.1g
```

As you can see, is the traditional way to get it using the tm package. The text are originally saved individually in different txt documents in a folder in my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my problem is that I am not able to reduce my term matrix to, lets
>   say, the 50 most relevant terms

If "relevancy" means frequency, you could do it like this:

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)
head(as.matrix(tdm))
tdm <- tdm[names(tail(sort(rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))), 50)), ]
tdm
# <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 50, documents: 20)>>
# ...
dtm <- dtm[, names(tail(sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm))), 50))]
inspect(dtm)
# <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 20, terms: 50)>>
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the number of terms, I prefer to use the quanteda package because you can choose the exact number of terms you want to use and then convert the document feature matrix to other object types if you need to perform other functions.

topfeatures() returns the top ranked n term counts.  Access the terms by taking the labels() of the vector.

Then, you can just subset your quanteda dfm by drilling down to the feature names.

Here is an example from my project where I reduce from over 120K terms to only 16K:

```
library(quanteda)
length(char_vec)

# [1] 758917

train.tokens <- tokens(char_vec, what = "word", ngrams = 1)
train.tokens <- tokens_select(train.tokens, stopwords(), selection = "remove")
train.tokens.dfm <- dfm(train.tokens)
dim(train.tokens.dfm)

# [1] 758917 128560

a <- topfeatures(train.tokens.dfm, n = 16000, decreasing = TRUE, scheme = c("count", "docfreq"), groups = NULL)
# Be sure to take the labels, because those are your terms you will use to search later
b <- labels(a)
length(b)

# [1] 16000

head(b)

# [1] "say"  "can"  "much" "will" "good" "get" 

train.tokens.dfm <- train.tokens.dfm[, which(train.tokens.dfm@Dimnames$features %in% b)]
dim(train.tokens.dfm)

# [1] 758917  16000
```

It isn't the shortest answer, but it works very effectively.

Now you can take your dfm and convert to a dtm as used in the tm package.

```
dtm <- convert(train.tokens.dfm, to = "tm", docvars = NULL)
class(dtm)

# [1] "DocumentTermMatrix"    "simple_triplet_matrix"
```

From here you can use the tm package to convert the dtm to a term document matrix, which appears to be what you need.

```
tdm <- as.TermDocumentMatrix(dtm)
class(tdm)

# [1] "TermDocumentMatrix"    "simple_triplet_matrix"

dim(tdm)

# [1]  16000 758917
```

From this point you should be able to perform your adjacency visualization.

Answer (score 0):

@agustin: if by "relevance" you mean pre-identified specific terms (could be named entities, organizations, or phrases) , you could just subset it on the  list of specific terms. For example, in the crude dataset, you may wish to examine "oil prices are expected to rise", "oil prices are expected to fall", "nigerian conflict", "iran oil" and "severe US winter":
`tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)
short.list<-c("oil prices are expected to rise", "oil prices are expected to fall", "nigerian conflict", "iran oil" and "severe US winter")
tdm.short.list<-tdm[rownames(tdm)%in%short.list,]
HTH`

Comment: Alternative is to simply run an intersect like so: `tdm.short.list<- tdm[ intersect(rownames(tdm), short.list)])`